# next js, updating page URL with ISR and SWR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

running into an issue with ISR and SWR on a dynamic page when updating content.

I have a page under `product/[slug]`, that uses staticProps and Paths to generate the pages/routes

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const slug = params!.slug;

  const products = await request(baseUrl, productsBySlug, {
    slug: slug,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      products: products,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const products = await request(baseUrl, allProductsQuery);

  const paths = products.products.map((product: Product) => ({
    params: { slug: product.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: true };
};
```

now, when I change the title of a product inside of the graphql-playground the slug is automatically updated (this is in laravel).

The problem here is that, the url won't change to reflect the potential slug update e.g.

my current url is `product/test-product`.

someone updates the name of the product to `Updated product` which is transformed to a slug which means the url is now `product/updated-product`.

But because the paths are statically generated next cannot find this and it gives an error when fetching.

I'm also using SWR to fetch data periodically and to keep it synced but this also seems to not work (unless i'm doing something wrong).

again on the `product/[slug]` page I have SWR running to update the data in real time for the current user, while using ISR to update it for any subsequent requests

```
  const variables = {
    slug: router.query.slug,
  };

  const { data, error } = useSWR([productsBySlug, variables], {
    fallbackData: products,
    revalidateOnMount: false,
  });


  if (router.isFallback) {
    return (
      <Box
        sx={{
          mx: "auto",
        }}
      >
        <Skeleton animation="wave" variant="circular" width={40} height={40} />
      </Box>
    );
  }

  if (!error && data) {
    return (
      <Box
        sx={{
          mx: "auto",
        }}
      >
        <Head>
          <title>Cross-poc | {data.productBySlug.slug}</title>
        </Head>
        <Button variant="outlined">
          <Link
            href={`edit/${encodeURIComponent(
              data.productBySlug.id
            )}/${encodeURIComponent(data.productBySlug.slug)}`}
          >
            Edit this product
          </Link>
        </Button>
        <ProductComponent
          showButton={false}
          key={data.productBySlug.id}
          product={data.productBySlug}
        />
      </Box>
    );
  }

  return <Alert severity="error">Could not fetch product info</Alert>;
```

If I'm on the product page when it's updated I alway get the Alert popup to display.

Is their anyway I can make URL's change dynamically with next as well?

Comment: _"it gives an error when fetching"_ - what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Hey, it's the alert itself that's being shown, most likely SWR being unable to validate the data because of slug changes? it's not exactly a next js error itself

Comment: Then isn't that an issue with the API?

Comment: Hey, the issue doesn't seem to be the API, basically, when I change a slug, next js and swr should "pick up" that the slug has changed and create a new route for that. bit hard to explain